# Find permutations of positive integers given sum and given number of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, combinations, permutation

How to find all permutations of positive integers for a given *sum* and given *number of elements*.

For example,

```
Input: sum = 4, number of elements = 2. 

Output: (1,3), (3,1), (2,2)
```

My thinking is, since I know the number of elements is `N`, I will create N arrays, each from 1 to the sum `S-1`. So for the example, I will start with two arrays, `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3]`. Then I will iterate through each array, something like

```
output = []
for x in array1:
  for y in array2:
    if x+y == target:
      output.append((x,y))
```

But I don't know how to make it for any `N`, since that would be variable number of for loops.

Now I have a second idea, I think this works.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
 
def find_permutations(S,N):
  x = np.asarray([x+1 for x in range(S)]*N)
  y = [seq for seq in combinations(x,N) if sum(seq)==S]
  return list(dict.fromkeys(y)) # remove duplicates

find_permutations(4,2)
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

But this is extremely slow, since it first create a very long array and find ALL combinations and then filter down. Something like `find_permutations(16,16)` takes extremely long time but it's obviously just `[(1,1,...,1)]`.

Comment: Can you please show some of your attempt at solving this.

Comment: Non-zero, positive integers?

Comment: What you are talking about are sometimes called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)). The linked article discusses compositions into a fixed number of pieces.

Comment: It looks like you want your homework done for you.

Comment: @Metropolis Yes, non-zero, positive integers.

Comment: you can remove the duplicates via a set: `set(find_permutations(5, 3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shorter one (edited to cover border case `k <= 1`):

```
def f(sum, k):
    if k < 1:
        return []
    if k == 1:
        return [(sum,)]
    if k == 2:
        return [(i,sum-i) for i in range(1, sum-k+2)]
    
    return [tup[:-1] + ab for tup in f(sum, k-1) for ab in f(tup[-1], 2)]
```

Test output:

```
f(2, 0)  # []
f(3, 1)  # [(3,)]
f(4, 2)  # [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
f(5, 3)  # [(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1)]
```

The algorithm takes the result for k-1 (i.e., `f(sum, k-1)`, recursively) and applies the same function to decompose all last elements to 2-tuples (i.e., `f(tup[-1], 2)`, again recursively).

---

Timing comparison:
10.000 repetitions of `f(5, 3)`: 0.07 s

for `get_combinations(5, 3)`: 0.30 s

and for `find_permutations(5, 3)`: 2.35 s

---

As for speed, I assume it's a similar situation like with Fibonacci sequence, this nested recursion is very inefficient and won't let you much beyond `f(20, 10)`.

Comment: It crashed when I try `f(1,1)`.

Comment: indeed, I should have noted it was for `k>1`; I'll update the code for border cases :)

Comment: Thanks. `f(3, 1)` should be just  `[(3,)]`, right? It shouldn't be `[(1,), (2,), (3,)]`.

Comment: duh, you're right of course, sorry, fixing the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution that will generate tuples that meet the requirements.

```
def get_combinations(target, num_elements, combinations=None):
    # Initialise an empty list
    if combinations == None:
        combinations = []
    # Calculate the sum of the current list of numbers
    combinations_sum = sum(combinations)
    # Check if the target is reached -> No further recursion necessary
    if (combinations_sum == target and len(combinations) == num_elements):
        # Return this combination of numbers
        yield tuple(combinations)
    else:
        # The combination of numbers doesn't yet total to target value
        # Iterate over each number from 1 to the target value 
        for number in range(1, target + 1):
            # Check that neither the target value nor number of elements will be exceeded
            if (combinations_sum + number <= target 
                and len(combinations) < num_elements):
                # Add the number to the list
                new_combo = combinations + [number]
                # Find all solutions for the list
                for c in get_combinations(target, num_elements, new_combo):
                    yield c
```

Sample output:

```
[c for c in get_combinations(4, 2)]
> [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```